# Using Pandas to load and read excel data

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to write code to load an excel file that will return:

1. the entire data frame
2. total number of rows
3. total number of columns

I wrote the following code but it gave an error: TypeError: cannot unpack non-iterable int object
Can you please help me with this, thank you!

```
def load_data():

    import pandas as pd  
    df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv") 
    num_rows = df.shape[0]  
    num_cols = df.shape[1]

    return num_rows
    return num_cols
df, num_rows, num_cols = load_data()
```

Comment: There is no point in having two return statements like that. The second one will never run. What IDE are you using, that wouldn't point that out? Don't put your import inside the function. Also, is there any point in making this a function in the first place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this!

```
import pandas as pd   

def load_data():

    df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv") 
    num_rows = df.shape[0]  
    num_cols = df.shape[1]

    return df, num_rows, num_cols

df, num_rows, num_cols = load_data()
```

you have to return your variables all at once. Best of luck!

Answer (score 1):

You return it wrong. You need  to return a tuple as follows

```
def load_data():

    import pandas as pd  
    df = pd.read_csv("myfile.csv") 
    num_rows = df.shape[0]  
    num_cols = df.shape[1]

    return df, num_rows, num_cols

df, num_rows, num_cols = load_data()
```

Answer (score 0):

A few things:

- The second `return` statement will never be run.
- Don't put import statements inside a function.
- I don't see much of a reason to even use a function for this.
- That isn't an *excel file*, it's just CSV.

```py
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('myfile.csv')
num_rows, num_cols = df.shape
```

Let me know if you have any questions :)